# SIte.com: Radio button in Form

Tags: site.com

In site.com I am making a form which have radio button and it's data I have to save in object.

I couldn't find a way to add radio button in a form.

If I am adding a custom code for radio button then how should I link it to object field. so that it's data can be stored in an object.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`<apex:selectRadio>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm)

Comment: Can you add a little bit more than just the name of the component? This post ended up in the review queue because it is very short. Worth revisiting  [answer] though I'm sure you've seen it before.

Comment: The link had details.  Short question, short answer.